# Legends values on a Parametric Plot

Tags: plotting, legending

i am wondering if mathematica  can automatically assign the value of x in each line in the parametric plot  as seen below.  This is my script. Is it possible to make this  plot in a contour plot?
Thank you [image]

```
   q0 = 80;
   Γ = 4/3;
   μ = 1/1000;
   l = μ/2;
   ε0 = 60;
   ψ0 = 1/5;   
   Rinit = 2/1000;
   Finit = 12/10;
   Δinit = 2;
   smax = 1.5 10^-8;

   sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
   h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]* μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)]
   M0[s_] := Sqrt[Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)]
   sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)

   U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)

   G[s_] := M0[s]/Sqrt[U0[s]] 
   sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
   γ0[s_] := ε0/((q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)*h0[s]); 
   γu0[s_] := Sqrt[γ0[s]^2 - 1];
   γu1[s_] := Δ0[s] Sqrt[γ0[s]^2 - 1];


   Dsonic[s_] := h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3
   ndΔ0[s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + Δ0[s]^Γ) 
   dF[s_] := (
    4 π R[s] (l^2 + R[s]^2) (h0[s]^2) (
    sG[s]^2) )/((l^2 + R[s] (R[s] - μ)) (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s])) ndΔ0[s] - 
   4 l^2 R[s]^3  μ + R[s] (-l^4 + R[s]^4) μ F[s]
```

Numerical differential equation

```
     Sol = NDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == ndΔ0[s], 
     R'[s] == Dsonic[s],  F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
     R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}, WorkingPrecision -> 32];

      xmin = 0.3;
      xmax = 0.6;
      dx = 0.1;
   

       ParametricPlot[
       Evaluate@Table[{(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*G[s]^2, 
       1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
       G[s]^2 (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
          G[s]^2)} /. Sol, {x, xmin, xmax, dx}], {s, 0, smax}, 
       AxesLabel -> {"\[CurlyPi]", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "γu", 
       AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 2):

With your definition above

```
xmin = 3/10;
xmax = 6/10;
dx = 1/10;
```

Plotting,

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[
   {(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*G[s]^2,
     1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
       G[s]^2 *
       (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
          G[s]^2)} /. Sol],
  {s, 0, smax}, {x, xmin, xmax},
  Axes -> False,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"ϖ", "z"}),
  PlotLabel -> Style["γu", 14],
  AspectRatio -> Full,
  PlotRange -> All,
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[(xmax - xmin)/dx + 1],
     Range[xmin, xmax, dx],
     LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm@x, 14]],
    {0.35, 0.4}]],
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
   Table[Tooltip[{(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*G[s]^2,
       1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
         G[s]^2 *
         (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
            G[s]^2)} /. Sol, x], {x, xmin, xmax, dx}],
  {s, 0, smax}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to implement  this in my original script ,using the same format as your post, and i am getting errors. "" Range does not have the appropriate bounds."   Is there something that is specific for this plot only and can not be generalised? Thanks again

Comment: I rationalized `xmin, xmax, and dx`. If you did not, you should change `Range[(xmax - xmin)/dx + 1]` to `Range[Round[(xmax - xmin)/dx] + 1]`. If that doesn't fix your problem, you would need to show the actual code that you are using.